# Visual C# Compiler (csc) unable to compile programs with latest language features

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn

For learning purposes, I use `csc.exe myprogram.cs` shipped with Visual Studio Community (my version 17.3.4) to compile basic C# programs. It mostly works, except when using what appears to be latest language features, for example, array range shorthand `array[0..]` or element from end shothand `array[^1]`.

For example, when trying to access `[^1]` element.

```
Arrays.cs(58,47): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Index' is not defined or imported
Arrays.cs(58,47): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Index..ctor'
```

I tried passing `-langversion:preview` to csc but still not working. Also I was unable to find proper `usings` for it to work.

Can I somehow get those features to work with basic csc compilation? They worked when I created `csproj` file and used `dotnet build`, but doing so was multiple times slower than using just csc. Thanks!

Comment: What .net sdk are you targeting

Comment: Why are you using `csc` and not `dotnet build`?

Comment: I executed csc with default params from Developer PowerShell, like this: `csc .\Arrays.cs` . I am using csc to get better speed... I know that I can use dotnet build, and it works for my file. It also seems interesting to me that csc behaves like this - works with some features and not with others.

Comment: How is it better speed? Have you even tried it?

Comment: In general you need a boatload of /ref parameters to tell the compiler about .net reference assemblies.  That's was made a bit easier, the same directory that contains csc.exe has a file named csc.rsp which contains precooked parameters. 
 But not for the new stuff, /ref:System.Runtime.dll is required here.

Comment: Hans, thank you a lot. However it still is not working with this additional ref. Am i doing it wrong? Command: `csc.exe /r:System.Runtime.dll .\Arrays.cs` , same error.

Comment: The compiler is just one component in a much larger ecosystem of tools here for any new .NET version; there's absolutely no reason to be directly invoking csc by hand here if you want to use new features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Arrays.cs(58,47): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Index' is not defined or imported
> Arrays.cs(58,47): error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'System.Index..ctor'

The compiler uses several types to lower index / range expressions to IL. One of those types is `System.Index`. This error is the compiler noting that it cannot find that type which is necessary to lower that expression to IL.

This feature was added as a part of `netcoreapp3.1` where `csc` defaults to compiling for .NET Framework applications. These types are not present in the standard set of references you get for .NET Framework hence this is why you get the error.

> They worked when I created csproj file and used dotnet build ...

That worked because your project file contained something like the following:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

This targeted your application for .NET Core, the `build` command passed along the standard references for that and those included the `System.Index` type.

> ... but doing so was multiple times slower than using just csc.

Building a .NET application involves more than just compiling code. It is finding the correct set of references, building dependencies, compiling and deploying the resulting binaries. It's more work hence it's going to take longer to complete. Multiple times slower is not expected, particularly for repeated executions, but it will take more time that invoking `csc`, or any ofeth other tools used in build, directly.